# pandas.read_csv ParserError: Expected x fields, saw y

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read a txt file that as different number of columns per row. Here's the beginning of my file:

```
60381 6
1 0.270 0.30 0.30 0.70 0.70
4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988
2 0.078 0.30 0.30 0.70 0.70
5.387 5.312 5.338 4.463 4.675 4.275 4.238 3.562 3.175 3.925 4.950 4.762
6 0.241 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
3.700 3.200 2.738 2.325 1.250 0.975 1.175 1.950 2.488 3.613 3.987 3.950
7 0.357 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
1.212 1.125 1.050 0.950 0.663 0.488 0.425 0.512 0.637 0.900 1.112 1.188
8 0.031 0.30 0.70 0.70 0.30
0.225 0.213 0.200 0.175 0.200 0.213 0.375 0.887 0.975 0.512 0.262 0.262
10 0.022 0.30 0.80 0.70 0.20
0.712 0.700 0.738 0.550 0.513 0.688 0.613 0.600 0.850 0.812 0.800 0.775
60382 5
6 0.197 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
3.700 3.200 2.738 2.325 1.250 0.975 1.175 1.950 2.488 3.613 3.987 3.950
7 0.413 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
1.212 1.125 1.050 0.950 0.663 0.488 0.425 0.512 0.637 0.900 1.112 1.188
8 0.016 0.30 0.70 0.70 0.30
0.225 0.213 0.200 0.175 0.200 0.213 0.375 0.887 0.975 0.512 0.262 0.262
10 0.111 0.30 0.80 0.70 0.20
0.712 0.700 0.738 0.550 0.513 0.688 0.613 0.600 0.850 0.812 0.800 0.775
11 0.263 0.30 0.50 0.70 0.50
1.812 1.388 1.087 0.825 0.538 0.400 0.338 0.400 0.500 0.925 0.962 1.100
```

I've tried using pandas read_csv to read it:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('./myfile.txt',header=None,sep='\s')
```

Which gives the following error:

```
ParserError: Expected 6 fields in line 3, saw 12. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

So my file doesn't have a multi-char delimiter or quotation marks. I've tried a solution for this I found in this forum, which suggested using:

```
data = pd.read_csv(open('./myfile.txt','r'), header=None,encoding='utf-8', engine='c')
```

Although this solves the error above, the array I'm presented with does not use space as a delimiter of columns, and the output has only 1 column:

[image: data output]

How should I read the file in order to get a column for each value? I don't mind if there are nan values that fill the rest.

Comment: `"the array I'm presented with does not use space as a delimiter of columns"` Why would it? you never told `read_csv` that the file uses white spaces as delimiter. You need to pass `delimiter=' '` to `read_csv`.

Comment: The lines with two elements (e.g. `60381 6`) seem like meta data to me. Are you sure this is a standard csv file?

Comment: Agree with @ayhan - that's what is throwing this off

Comment: @DeepSpace Well, I didn't want to make the post too long. I did try adding the delimiter `sep=\s` at the end, but I got another error: **ValueError: the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex)**. Using `sep=\s+' and/or removing the `engine = 'c'` gives again a ParserError.

Comment: @ayhan The original file is a *.txt, and looks exactly like what I shared. I tried using read_csv because it's what I've seen people tend suggest to use when treating with files that has different number of columns per row. Any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Where did the file come from? Generally these files have some explanations about the format, or how the file is structured. If you downloaded it from a web site, look for a description of the file in the same page.

Comment: @ayhan File was taken from [this site](http://www.hydro.washington.edu/SurfaceWaterGroup/Data/vic_global_0.5deg.html), and it's a part of the _global_veg_param_new.txt_ file that can be found in the **tar** at the bottom. Sadly, it doesn't provide any information about the file format. The readme found in the tar file gives the same information that shows in the link I provided.

Comment: It mentions a format called [netCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/) and there are some software on the site if you want to try.

Comment: @ayhan I'm familiar with the netCDF format but it has nothing to do with this one. They just mention they used the netCDF files to take  information to produce the file I'm using. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've managed to get the data in a single column, you can use [`Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to workaround this issue.

Here is an example with some sample data you provided (you can use any string or a regex as a delimiter in `split()`) :

```
df[0].str.split(' ', expand=True)

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9   \
0  0.270   0.30   0.30   0.70   0.70   None   None   None   None   None
1  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988
```

If you do this, then you might as well create the dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(open(...).readlines())` or something like that, since you don't benefit at all from `read_csv()`, and your file isn't exactly a standard csv file.

```
# f is a StringIO with some of your sample data to simulate a file
df = pd.DataFrame(line.strip().split(' ') for line in f)

       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9   \
0   60381      6   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
1       1  0.270   0.30   0.30   0.70   0.70   None   None   None   None
2   4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988  4.988
3       2  0.078   0.30   0.30   0.70   0.70   None   None   None   None
4   5.387  5.312  5.338  4.463  4.675  4.275  4.238  3.562  3.175  3.925
```

Of course, you can also fix the input file by making sure every line contains the same number of columns, which will solve the `ParserError` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider iteratively rebuilding the text file and then `pd.read_table()` on cleaned text version:

```
from io import StringIO

txt="""
60381 6
1 0.270 0.30 0.30 0.70 0.70
4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988
2 0.078 0.30 0.30 0.70 0.70
5.387 5.312 5.338 4.463 4.675 4.275 4.238 3.562 3.175 3.925 4.950 4.762
6 0.241 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
3.700 3.200 2.738 2.325 1.250 0.975 1.175 1.950 2.488 3.613 3.987 3.950
7 0.357 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
1.212 1.125 1.050 0.950 0.663 0.488 0.425 0.512 0.637 0.900 1.112 1.188
8 0.031 0.30 0.70 0.70 0.30
0.225 0.213 0.200 0.175 0.200 0.213 0.375 0.887 0.975 0.512 0.262 0.262
10 0.022 0.30 0.80 0.70 0.20
0.712 0.700 0.738 0.550 0.513 0.688 0.613 0.600 0.850 0.812 0.800 0.775
60382 5
6 0.197 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
3.700 3.200 2.738 2.325 1.250 0.975 1.175 1.950 2.488 3.613 3.987 3.950
7 0.413 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40
1.212 1.125 1.050 0.950 0.663 0.488 0.425 0.512 0.637 0.900 1.112 1.188
8 0.016 0.30 0.70 0.70 0.30
0.225 0.213 0.200 0.175 0.200 0.213 0.375 0.887 0.975 0.512 0.262 0.262
10 0.111 0.30 0.80 0.70 0.20
0.712 0.700 0.738 0.550 0.513 0.688 0.613 0.600 0.850 0.812 0.800 0.775
11 0.263 0.30 0.50 0.70 0.50
1.812 1.388 1.087 0.825 0.538 0.400 0.338 0.400 0.500 0.925 0.962 1.100
"""

for line in StringIO(txt):

    if len(line) == 8:
        header = line
        next
    if len(line) == 28 or len(line) == 29:
        firstdata = line
        next
    if len(line) == 72:
        seconddata = header + ' ' + firstdata + ' ' + line
        print(seconddata.replace("\n", ""))
```

Output

```
# 60381 6 1 0.270 0.30 0.30 0.70 0.70 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988 4.988
# 60381 6 2 0.078 0.30 0.30 0.70 0.70 5.387 5.312 5.338 4.463 4.675 4.275 4.238 3.562 3.175 3.925 4.950 4.762
# 60381 6 6 0.241 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40 3.700 3.200 2.738 2.325 1.250 0.975 1.175 1.950 2.488 3.613 3.987 3.950
# 60381 6 7 0.357 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40 1.212 1.125 1.050 0.950 0.663 0.488 0.425 0.512 0.637 0.900 1.112 1.188
# 60381 6 8 0.031 0.30 0.70 0.70 0.30 0.225 0.213 0.200 0.175 0.200 0.213 0.375 0.887 0.975 0.512 0.262 0.262
# 60381 6 10 0.022 0.30 0.80 0.70 0.20 0.712 0.700 0.738 0.550 0.513 0.688 0.613 0.600 0.850 0.812 0.800 0.775
# 60382 5 6 0.197 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40 3.700 3.200 2.738 2.325 1.250 0.975 1.175 1.950 2.488 3.613 3.987 3.950
# 60382 5 7 0.413 0.30 0.60 0.70 0.40 1.212 1.125 1.050 0.950 0.663 0.488 0.425 0.512 0.637 0.900 1.112 1.188
# 60382 5 8 0.016 0.30 0.70 0.70 0.30 0.225 0.213 0.200 0.175 0.200 0.213 0.375 0.887 0.975 0.512 0.262 0.262
# 60382 5 10 0.111 0.30 0.80 0.70 0.20 0.712 0.700 0.738 0.550 0.513 0.688 0.613 0.600 0.850 0.812 0.800 0.775
# 60382 5 11 0.263 0.30 0.50 0.70 0.50 1.812 1.388 1.087 0.825 0.538 0.400 0.338 0.400 0.500 0.925 0.962 1.100
```

Now for file import into pandas, consider writing new output to text file:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f1, open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
   for line in f1:
      if len(line) == 8:
          header = line
          next
      if len(line) == 28 or len(line) == 29:
          firstdata = line
          next
      if len(line) == 72:
          seconddata = header + ' ' + firstdata + ' ' + line
          f2.write(seconddata.replace("\n", ""))

df = read.table('output.txt', header=None, sep="\\s+")
```

Comment: This produces a file with only 1 row and a column per value. It also misses some data, since not all the headers have the same amount if **firstada** and **seconddata**.